# Too many arguments for constructor

Tags: scala, constructor, tdd, classname

Trying to learn some Scala.

I have the following classes in my project:

```
package com.fluentaws

class AwsProvider(val accountId: String, val accountSecret: String) {

 def AwsAccount = new AwsAccount(accountId, accountSecret)

}

class AwsAccount(val accountId : String, val accountSecret : String) {

}
```

And the following test:

```
package com.fluentaws

import org.scalatest._

class AwsProvider extends FunSuite {

  test("When providing AwsProvider with AWS Credentials we can retrieve an AwsAccount with the same values") {

    val awsAccountId = "abc"
    val awsAccountSecret = "secret"

    val awsProvider = new AwsProvider(awsAccountId, awsAccountSecret)

    val awsAccount = awsProvider.AwsAccount

    assert(awsAccount.accountId == awsAccountId)
    assert(awsAccount.accountSecret == awsAccountSecret)
  }

}
```

When my test-suite runs, I get the compile-time error:

> too many arguments for constructor AwsProvider:
>   ()com.fluentaws.AwsProvider [error]     val awsProvider = new
>   AwsProvider(awsAccountId, awsAccountSecret) [error]

From the error message it looks like it sees a constructor with zero parameters ?

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Oh, .. maybe I am redefining a new class called AwsProvider and not extending the existing one

Comment: You should rename your test-class.

Comment: Yeah, that was it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a typical rookie mistake. I fixed my test-class' name, because using the same name would shadow the original name, whereby I was actually testing my test's class:

```
package com.fluentaws

import org.scalatest._

class AwsProviderTestSuite extends FunSuite {

  test("When providing AwsProvider with AWS Credentials we can retrieve an AwsAccount with the same values") {

    val awsAccountId = "abc"
    val awsAccountSecret = "secret"

    val awsProvider = new AwsProvider(awsAccountId, awsAccountSecret)

    val awsAccount = awsProvider.AwsAccount

    assert(awsAccount.accountId == awsAccountId)
    assert(awsAccount.accountSecret == awsAccountSecret)
  }

}
```

Now it passes.